# Declaring a global method in Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

If I have the following module

```
module UserSession
 $user_array = factory_girl_users.values

 def factory_girl_users
  Hash[:user_1 => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:automated_user), :user_2 => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:automated_user_1)]
 end
end
World(UserSession)
```

How do I access the factory_girl_users method, since at the moment I'm getting:

```
undefined method `factory_girl_users' for UserSession:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I can't think what is responsible for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can define a module method

```
module UserSession

  def self.factory_girl_users
    Hash[:user_1 => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:automated_user), :user_2 => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:automated_user_1)]
   end

  def self.user_array
    factory_girl_users.values
  end
end
```

To access the `user_array` You would do `UserSession.user_array`.